# Kendo UI DropDownListFor Set SelectedValue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Kendo UI on an MVC application.  We have a grid and when the user opens the row for editing we have a dropDownList that holds company names.  I'm trying to get the DDL to default to the company name that's pertinent to the row.

Here's the column code:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.company_business_name).Width(220).Title("Company")
    .EditorTemplateName("CompanyName");
```

and here's the editorTemplate code:

```
@model  string

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Companies"])
 )
```

and the method that fills the DDL:

```
    private void PopulateCompanies()
    {
        var companyList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Companies"] as string))
        {
            companyList = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["Companies"];
        }
        else
        {
            companyList = new DataAccess().GetCompanies(CurrentSettings.getUser().userId);
            CacheCompanies(companyList);
        }

        ViewData["Companies"] = companyList;
    }
```

EDIT:

Updated the code.  The DDL still populates but I'm still not getting the selected value when I click "edit" on the grid row. Feel like I'm close here, help!

Comment: I would suggest to start by looking at the Custom Editor demo(http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom) and the Foreignkey column demo(http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn).  Note that in order to see *everything* that is going on, you will have to open the demo project that is installed with Kendo MVC as the online MVC demos don't show every file of interest, in the case of the custome editor demo, it does not show you the EditorTemplate, The demo project should be found here: <Telerik UI for MVC installation folder>\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Examples

Comment: What does `GetCompanies` return? Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Editor Template's model is your entire model, not the `company_business_name` property (Very bad name for a property, by the way. You need to follow the standard naming conventions).

You don't even need to fill the drop down list.

Your Editor Template should be something like this:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataSource(x => 
        x.Read(read => read.Action("GetCompanies", "AddEntry"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks ataravati, I modified the code to mirror your suggestion.  The DDL populates but still not getting the selected value.

And you're preaching to the choir about the naming convention, but I inherited this little monster.

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild in your DDL, try to set `.ValuePrimitive(true)` and see if that works.